# Understanding network configuration for Vapor+nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, nginx

I have my Vapor App `MyApp` running on `localhost:8080` on my Ubuntu server and installed nginx to connect to it via `<server-ip>:80`.
It works, but I don't understand the following part of it:

To get it to work I followed a [small tutorial on how to host a Vapor app](https://medium.com/@ahmedraad/how-to-deploy-vapor-app-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-run-it-in-production-eef18f7b4f05). A part of an nginx config file had to be set up like:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

I now should've been able to reach `MyApp` using `<server-ip>:80`, but this didn't work. As `MyApp` starts with the prompt:

> Server starting on http://localhost:8080

I changed the server block in the nginx config to:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; // Changed to localhost
    }
}
```

This worked and I am now able to reach `MyApp`!

netstat shows the following entries:

```
[...]:~# netstat -antp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address     Foreign Address  State     PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80        0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN    1106/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53     0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN    601/systemd-resolve
[...] // my ssh connection
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8080          :::*             LISTEN    8145/<MyApp>
tcp6       0      0 :::80             :::*             LISTEN    1106/nginx: master
```

- So it seems my Vapor app runs on tcp6. I'm new to server development and thought of localhost as an equivalent to `127.0.0.1`. Why did my changes make it work?
- With my change to localhost, might I run into any other problems?

Answer (score 2):

The name `localhost` is equivalent to the IPv6 address `::1` in addition to the IPv4 address `127.0.0.1`.

For the last ... almost 20 years or so, IPv6 has been the preferred protocol over IPv4, so when an IPv6 address is available for a name it will be tried first.

This means that you should expect `localhost` connections to be made to `::1` on virtually every modern device, unless someone has gone to great lengths to disable IPv6. And on some operating systems such as Windows, IPv6 cannot be disabled anyway, so `localhost` is always expected to connect to `::1`.